# Unable to read shared memory data using boost created by Qt

Tags: qt, boost, shared-memory

I've created a Qt shared memory program to write a string into shared memory. Now After writing, I need to read it from Boost program. I tried using simple programs, but I couldn't read the string using Boost interprocess.

Here is the Qt code that is writing into the shared memory. And I'm double checking if the string is written by reading from the shared memory from the same program.

```
void CDialog::loadString()
{
    if(sharedMemory.isAttached())
    {
        if(!sharedMemory.detach())
        {
            lbl->setText("Unable to detach from Shared Memory");
            return;
        }
    }

    lbl->setText("Click on Top Button");

    char sString[] = "my string";

    QBuffer buffer;
    buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);

    QDataStream out(&buffer);
    out << sString;

    int size = buffer.size();
    qDebug() << size;

    if(!sharedMemory.create(size))
    {
        lbl->setText("Unable to create shared memory segment");
        qDebug() << lbl->text();
    }
    sharedMemory.lock();
    char *to = (char *) sharedMemory.data();
    const char *from = buffer.data();
    memcpy(to, from, qMin(sharedMemory.size(), size));
    sharedMemory.unlock();

    char * str;
    QDataStream in(&buffer);
    sharedMemory.lock();
    buffer.setData((char *)sharedMemory.constData(), sharedMemory.size());
    buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);
    in >> str;
    sharedMemory.unlock();
    qDebug() << str;
}
```

And I'm reading it from boost using the same key which I've provided in the Qt program.
Below is the Boost program code -

```
int main()
{
  boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object shdmem(boost::interprocess::open_only, "Highscore", boost::interprocess::read_only);

  boost::interprocess::offset_t size; 
  if (shdmem.get_size(size)) 
    std::cout << "Shared Mem Size: " << size << std::endl; 

  boost::interprocess::mapped_region region2(shdmem, boost::interprocess::read_only); 
  char *i2 = static_cast<char *>(region2.get_address()); 
  std::cout << i2 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Kindly help me in reading the shared memory data from Boost program.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the Qt docs:

> Warning: QSharedMemory changes the key in a Qt-specific way. It is therefore currently not possible to use the shared memory of non-Qt applications with QSharedMemory.

You will probably need to use Boost on both sides.